# What do we need to get a transit visa at Delhi international airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, del, afghan-citizens

I have two flights. From Seoul to Delhi and from Delhi to Afghanistan, with two different airlines and two tickets. At Delhi I have to take my baggage by myself and transfer it to my second Delhi-Afghanistan flight. In this case I need to have a transit visa to pass the passport control and to get my luggage. So I am not entering India but just want to take my luggage. Can I get the transit visa exactly in the day which I arrive at Delhi international airport ? or must I get the visa before my travel ?

Comment: what is your nationality?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid In his other question he said he is a national of Afghanistan.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get a visa before you travel.  On arrival visa is not available for citizens of Afghanistan.

The "on arrival" visa has been replaced with the online e-visa. The countries whose citizens are eligible to apply for an online visa is [available on the official website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html).

If your country of citizenship is not listed there, then you need to apply for a regular visa from the Indian embassy.